# django render_to_response

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm putting

```
...}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

at the end of all my `render_to_response`'s. I'm sure this is not right. Can anyone tell me when I should be using these?

Comment: It is right, but like you point out, it shouldn't be necessary. It should be opt out, not opt in. Thankfully, 1.3 addresses this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it "right". This means that all of the Context Processors will run on this view, and you will have access to all of the juicy bits in your template.

The other way to do this is to use `direct_to_template`, which saves you having to instantiate a RequestContext object, but has the same outcomes.

Comment: If you always need it then why do I always have to put it at the end of my `render_to_response`'s? Surely it should just be hidden!

Comment: You don't always need it though.

Comment: Brian is right: you don't always need it. However, in practice I find I use it every time: then you get access to `messages`, if you have that Context Processor installed, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [Django 1.3](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#everything-else) you can use the [render()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut function so you don't have to explicitly write `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` for each view .

> Combines a given template with a given
>   context dictionary and returns an
>   HttpResponse object with that rendered
>   text.
>
> render() is the same as a call to
>   render_to_response() with a
>   context_instance argument that forces
>   the use of a RequestContext.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yet to move to 1.3. Not to sure what it's going to break