# Django get the foreign key object value

Tags: python, django

I wrote a model and saved some data, but now I don't know how to query the object along with the foreign key model.

Here is my `models.py`:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    title_en = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class MovieImage(models.Model):
    movieimage = models.ForeignKey(Movie,null=True,blank=True)            
    img_link = models.URLField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

`view.py`:

```
def index(request):
   obj = Movie.objects.all()
   contacts = get_paginator(request, obj, 10)
   return render_to_response("movie/index.html",
                          {'title': title ,'obj':obj,'contacts':contacts},
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And `movie/index.html`:

```
     {% for o in obj %}
     <div class="col-md-12  item">
        <p><h3>{{ o.title }}</h3></p>
        <div class="pic">
             {{ o.img_link }}  <!--I want to show the img_link but don't know how to do this -->
        </div>
     </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I know I can use `o.title` ,`o.entitle` to get the value. But I don't know how to get the value in foreign key model from there

Comment: with your modelset, you can have multiple `MovieImage`s for a single `Movie`. You only want to get one of them? I also guess that when you write `YahooMovie` you mean `Movie`

Comment: yes.It's Movie. I edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - Some naming conventions - `obj` is a terribly general name that doesn't mean anything. It's probably a good idea to use something like `movies`. Also, if the model is named `MovieImage`, why have a field called `img_link`? That's kinda repetitive, don't you think? This way would be better:

```
#models.py
class MovieImage(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie,null=True,blank=True)            
    src   = models.URLField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

Then you could do:

```
#views.py

def index(request):
    movies = Movie.objects.all() # movies instead of obj
    contacts = get_paginator(request, movies, 10)
    return render(request, "movie/index.html",
                  {'title': title ,'movies':movies,'contacts':contacts})
```

finally, for the actual answer - the default name for the related objects are `foo_set` (in your case, `movieimage_set`) which you can iterate over like so:

```
# html
{% for movie in movies %}
<div class="col-md-12  item">
    <p><h3>{{ movie.title }}</h3></p>
    <div class="pic">
       {% for image in movie.movieimage_set.all %}
           <img src="{{ image.src }}"> <!-- I am assuming you actually want to show the image, not just the link -->
       {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**p.s.**
You might've noticed, I replaced `render_to_response` in the views with `render`. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371005/django-why-should-i-ever-use-the-render-to-response-at-all)

Comment: @user2492364 sure thing, happy to have helped =]

Answer (score 2):

As I told you on comments, you can have more than a `MovieImage` for each `Movie`, soy you need to iterate over them.

```
{% for o in obj %}
 <div class="col-md-12  item">
    <p><h3>{{ o.title }}</h3></p>
    <div class="pic">
        {% for image in o.movieimage_set.all %}
             {{image.img_link}}
        {% empty %}
             <p>This obj doesn't have any image</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```